# Python how to obtain ID_Token to use with Open ID Connect from using account authentication with oauthlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, jwt

Right now I can obtain an access token using requests_oauthlib and a scope. However I'd like to be able to get the full ID_Token and was wondering if it was possible with the way I'm doing things.

```
import flask
import requests_oauthlib
import os
import requests


CLIENT_ID = "ClientIDKEY"
CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENTSECRETKEY"
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:5000/callback"

AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
USERINFO_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json"
SCOPE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"

# This allows us to use a plain HTTP callback
os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return """
    <a href="/login">Login with Google</a> 
    """


@app.route("/login")
def login():
    simplelogin = requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session(
        CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=SCOPE_URL
    )
    authorization_url, _ = simplelogin.authorization_url(AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL)

    return flask.redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    simplelogin = requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
    simplelogin.fetch_token(
        TOKEN_URL, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, authorization_response=flask.request.url
    )
    URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=" + str(simplelogin.access_token)
    req = requests.get(url = URL)
    print(req.json)
    return f"""
    Ok
    """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", debug=True)
```

I'd like to either obtain the ID token when authenticating instead of the Access Token, or simply use the Access Token from the authentication to obtain the ID_Token.

The final result here, not in the scope of this question, is to use the jwt token and validate it with cloud endpoints, so they can be used on a REST api on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do it with python 2.7 (since for some reason they just decided to use 2.7) but the concept is the same.

In the SCOPE_URL I passed ["openid"], which made the request return and ID_Token. I then used that ID_Token and made a call such as:

```
AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
USERINFO_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json"
SCOPE_URL = ["openid"]

(...)    

@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    simplelogin = requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
    simplelogin.fetch_token(
        TOKEN_URL, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, authorization_response=flask.request.url
    )
    ID_Token = simplelogin.token.get('id_token')
    URL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=" + str(ID_Token)
    req = requests.get(url=URL)
    print(req.content)
    return """
    Ok
    """
```